# Objective C - Why 64bit means different variable types

Tags: objective-c, nsinteger

I have heard that people use types such as NSInteger or CGFloat rather than int or float is because of something to do with 64bit systems. I still don't understand why that is necessary, even though I do it throughout my own code. Basically, why would I need a larger integer for a 64bit system?

People also say that it is not necessary in iOS at the moment, although it may be necessary in the future with 64bit iphones and such.

Comment: To store integers into registers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially it boils down to this: If you use CGFloat/NSInteger/etc, Apple can make backwards-incompatible changes and you can *mostly* update your app by just recompiling your code. You really don't want to be going through your app, checking every use of `int` and `double`.

What backwards-incompatible changes? Plenty!

- M68K to PowerPC
- 64-bit PowerPC
- PowerPC to x86
- x86-64 (I'm not sure if this came before or after iOS.)
- iOS

`CGFloat` means "the floating-point type that CoreGraphics" uses: `double` on OS X and `float` on iOS. If you use `CGFloat`, your code will work on both platforms without unnecessarily losing performance (on iOS) or precision (on OS X).

`NSInteger` and `NSUInteger` are less clear-cut, but they're used approximately where you might use `ssize_t` or `size_t` in standard C. `int` or `unsigned int` simply isn't big enough on 64-bit OS X, where you might have a list with more than ~2 billion items. (The unsignedness doesn't increase it to 4 billion due to the way `NSNotFound` is defined.)

Answer (score 5):

It is all explained here:

[Introduction to 64-Bit Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/intro/intro.html)

In the section Major 64-Bit Changes:

[image]

> **Data Type Size and Alignment**
>
> OS X uses two data models: ILP32 (in
>   which integers, long integers, and pointers are 32-bit quantities) and
>   LP64 (in which integers are 32-bit quantities, and long integers and
>   pointers are 64-bit quantities). Other types are equivalent to their
>   32-bit counterparts (except for size_t and a few others that are
>   defined based on the size of long integers or pointers).
>
> While almost all UNIX and Linux implementations use LP64, other
>   operating systems use various data models. Windows, for example, uses
>   LLP64, in which long long variables and pointers are 64-bit
>   quantities, while long integers are 32-bit quantities. Cray, by
>   contrast, uses ILP64, in which int variables are also 64-bit
>   quantities.
>
> In OS X, the default alignment used for data structure layout is
>   natural alignment (with a few exceptions noted below). Natural
>   alignment means that data elements within a structure are aligned at
>   intervals corresponding to the width of the underlying data type. For
>   example, an int variable, which is 4 bytes wide, would be aligned on a
>   4-byte boundary.

There is **a lot more** that you can read in this document. It is very well written. I strongly recommend it to you.